# SQL Populate column value based on ID in other column and Group by date

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

i have a table with 3 columns with the data as follow

[image]

I Would like to create a table similar to following columns

```
    Date      | Number    | Beverage  | Type | Receipt No
    10/9/2019 | 1111111111| Chocolate | Hot  | INV00001
    10/9/2019 | 2222222222| Orange    | Ice  | INV00002
```

and second, i would like to show the table with total sales by date

```
    Date      | Total Sales
    10/9/2019 | 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current table is using a key-value store design.  You may generate the output you want using pivoting logic:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_id = 27  THEN value END) AS Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_id = 4   THEN value END) AS Number,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_id = 82  THEN value END) AS Beverage,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_id = 104 THEN value END) AS Type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN element_id = 108 THEN value END) AS "Receipt No"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

To find total sales by date, where each sale corresponds to a unique `id` value, we can try:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS total_sales
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN element_id = 27  THEN value END) AS date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
) t
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Note: Demo in SQL Server, but the query should run on pretty much any other database as well.

Answer (score 1):

for your first query

```
select f.value as Date, a.value as Number, c.value as Beverage, d.value as Type, d.value as "Receipt No"
from 
(select distinct id, value from table) a
left join table b on a.id = b.id and b.element_id = 4
left join table c on a.id = c.id and c.element_id = 82
left join table d on a.id = d.id and d.element_id = 104
left join table e on a.id = e.id and e.element_id = 108
left join table f on a.id = f.id and f.element_id = 27
```

for total sales

```
select value as Date as TotalSales from table
where element_id = 27
group by value
```

Comment: is working, just an typo error on select statement, should be
select f.value as Date, a.value as Number, c.value as Beverage, d.value as Type, e.value as "Receipt No"

thank you